# How can I disable the startup sound on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, audio, boot, system-sounds

How can I disable the startup sound on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6?

I have tried using Psst (deactivated now because it didn't work)

[image]

And also the Startup Sound Preference Pane:

[image]

Looks like Psst works for 10.8 Lion and the preference pane works for 10.4 and maybe 10.5.

How can I disable the startup sound on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6?

Comment: Quoting [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16425/startupsound.prefpane): "Fixed compatibility issue with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard." — So, are you sure about the preference pane?

Comment: In the screenshot you can see in the bottom left that the version is 1.1b3 (same as the link you provided). You can also see that I have "mute" checked. My computer makes the startup sound when I restart so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Makes sense. Was just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

This used to work back in the Panther (10.3) era on an old G4.  I haven't tested it lately, but it's pretty simple:

Just hold the hotkey for "mute" on your keyboard while your computer is starting up.  It isn't sticky, and may only work with an Apple keyboard, but it's the only method I know.

Comment: Startup shortcuts havent changed much - should work